# React native android application gets stuck on ProfileInstaller on the first run

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-hermes

I recently upgraded my dependencies and upgraded from `React Native` `0.68.5` to `0.72.6`, enabled `hermes` and `fabric`, I will say everything went well except for one thing, on Android I started experiencing a weird behavior where the application would get stuck on this line:

[image]

`ProfileInstaller com.appName D  Installing profile for com.appName`

This happens the first time the application is opened, after that the application launches without much issue.

Below is my package.json file:

```
  {
    "name": "appName",
    "version": "1.10.02",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "ios:development": "react-native run-ios --scheme \"appName Dev Debug\"",
      "ios:dev-release": "react-native run-ios --scheme \"appName Prod Debug\"",
      "ios:release": "react-native run-ios --scheme \"appName Prod Release\"",
      "postinstall": "patch-package",
      "start": "react-native start",
      "install:all": "yarn install && cd ios && pod install && cd ..",
      "start-reset-cache": "react-native start --reset-cache",
      "ios:clean": "cd ios && xcodebuild clean && rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods && rm -rf Pods && rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/* && pod cache clean --all && pod deintegrate && pod setup && pod install && cd ..",
      "test": "jest",
      "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
      "android-dev": "react-native run-android --variant=developmentdebug",
      "android-dev-release": "react-native run-android --variant=developmentrelease",
      "android-prod": "react-native run-android --variant=productiondebug",
      "android-prod-release": "react-native run-android --variant=productionrelease",
      "prettier": "prettier --ignore-path .prettierignore \"**/*.+(js|json|ts|tsx)\"",
      "android:apk": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease --no-daemon --full-stacktrace",
      "logcat": "adb logcat *:D ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V",
      "android:clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache",
      "android:release": "cd android && ./gradlew app:bundleProductionRelease",
      "android:release-apk": "cd android && ./gradlew app:assembleProductionRelease",
      "bump-patch": "npm version patch --no-git-tag-version && bundle exec fastlane bump",
      "bump-minor": "npm version minor --no-git-tag-version && bundle exec fastlane bump",
      "bump-major": "npm version major --no-git-tag-version && bundle exec fastlane bump"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@notifee/react-native": "^5.7.0",
      "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
      "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "1.11.2",
      "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
      "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.0",
      "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.8",
      "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
      "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.20",
      "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
      "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
      "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
      "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
      "@sentry/react-native": "^5.4.0",
      "@tanstack/query-async-storage-persister": "^4.29.1",
      "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.29.3",
      "@tanstack/react-query-persist-client": "^4.29.3",
      "axios": "^0.22.0",
      "axios-auth-refresh": "^3.3.6",
      "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
      "base-64": "^1.0.0",
      "buffer": "^6.0.3",
      "color": "^4.2.3",
      "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
      "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
      "entities": "^4.4.0",
      "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
      "eslint-plugin-ft-flow": "^2.0.1",
      "expo": "^49.0.0",
      "expo-constants": "^14.4.2",
      "expo-localization": "^14.5.0",
      "expo-modules-core": "^1.5.11",
      "htmlparser2-without-node-native": "^3.9.2",
      "husky": "^8.0.1",
      "i18n-js": "^4.3.2",
      "immer": "^9.0.15",
      "lodash": "^4.17.21",
      "mitt": "^2.1.0",
      "moment": "^2.29.4",
      "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
      "path-to-regexp": "^6.2.1",
      "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
      "prettier": "^2.7.1",
      "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
      "pushy-react-native": "^1.0.32",
      "react": "18.2.0",
      "react-content-loader": "^6.2.0",
      "react-dom": "17.0.2",
      "react-hook-form": "^7.34.1",
      "react-native": "0.72.6",
      "react-native-android-badge": "^0.5.0",
      "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
      "react-native-blob-util": "^0.18.6",
      "react-native-compressor": "^1.5.2",
      "react-native-config": "^1.4.11",
      "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
      "react-native-date-ranges": "github:clistesoft/react-native-date-ranges",
      "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
      "react-native-device-detection": "^0.2.1",
      "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.1",
      "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
      "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
      "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.10",
      "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
      "react-native-flash-message": "^0.4.1",
      "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
      "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
      "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.19",
      "react-native-image-colors": "^1.5.1",
      "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
      "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.5",
      "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
      "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
      "react-native-keychain": "^6.2.0",
      "react-native-logs": "^3.0.4",
      "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
      "react-native-mov-to-mp4": "^0.2.2",
      "react-native-otp-textinput": "^0.0.7",
      "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.25",
      "react-native-paper": "5.10.5",
      "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.1",
      "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
      "react-native-phone-input": "^1.3.4",
      "react-native-ratings": "^7.3.0",
      "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
      "react-native-redash": "^18.1.0",
      "react-native-restart": "^0.0.24",
      "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
      "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
      "react-native-share": "^7.8.0",
      "react-native-shared-element": "^0.8.8",
      "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
      "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
      "react-native-svg": "^12.4.4",
      "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
      "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
      "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
      "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.1",
      "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
      "react-native-webview": "^13.3.0",
      "react-native-wheel-picker-android": "^2.0.6",
      "react-navigation-shared-element": "^3.1.3",
      "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
      "realm": "^12.2.1",
      "redux": "^4.0.5",
      "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
      "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
      "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
      "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
      "use-async-queue": "^2.1.5",
      "use-immer": "^0.7.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.18.10",
      "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
      "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.9",
      "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
      "@types/react-native": "^0.69.5",
      "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.12",
      "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.14",
      "babel-jest": "^28.1.3",
      "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
      "eslint": "^8.23.1",
      "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.3.1",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
      "jest": "^28.1.3",
      "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
      "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^3.2.2",
      "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
      "react-phone-number-input": "^3.2.7",
      "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
      "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.2",
      "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.3",
      "typescript": "^4.7.4"
    },
    "jest": {
      "preset": "react-native"
    }
  }
```

Honestly at this point I am a little lost, I have no idea why this is happening, even worse, this only happens on Android, the iOS variant works just fine.